# How to generate relocation table

Tags: c++, windows, x86, portable-executable

I am writing a compiler from scratch with absolutely no dependency, so I am trying to generate a binary without llvm,...

I already figured out how to generate headers and .text section, but for the .rdata and .reloc section I am not really sure that I can generate them without support of .lib linking.

The code I try to put in the executable calls few win32 functions like WriteConsole,...

So normally we link the kernel32.lib to be able to use the associated kernel32.dll.

Is there a way to generate location table without parsing the kernel32.lib? Or if I reverse engineering the kernel32.lib I will find the .rdata and .reloc sections. In this case I suppose that I'll have to correct addresses of the .reloc section to be able to handle multiple libraries?

Comment: Relocations are not (directly) used to import functions from DLLs - you need to use the functionality of the [.idata section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-idata-section), which requires only the name of the DLL, and the name/ordinal of the function(s) being imported.

Comment: Ok so it is curious that my reference binary I made with VS use .rdata and .reloc section to achieve the same thing (it doesn't have .idata section). It seems a bit simpler to use .idata to make the PE launcher loading DLL at the same time as the binary. If I want a fast loading I may have to parse .def files to use ordinal instead of names, right? And I will have to ask the user in which DLL are function he want to import.

Comment: Without knowing the details of your "reference binary" (source, compilation settings, etc.), it's not possible to comment further on what it's doing. Using the .idata section is the standard way to import functions from DLLs on Windows. If the function is exported by name, then you should import it by name, since ordinals are not guaranteed to be consistent across different versions of the same DLL.

Comment: @iridium thx a lot, I understand much more how it works now. I will win a lot of time now I know where to go.

Comment: Presence of section named **.idata**  is not essential for import functionality. Windows loader is controlled by 2nd (IMPORT) and 13th (IAT) items of  data-directory table located in *optional header*.