# How to call functions in IAT with x86 opcodes

Tags: windows, x86, intel, portable-executable

This question follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73284255/how-to-generate-relocation-table).

I managed the creation of the .idata section with import table, ILT, IAT and Hint/Name table. When I use a PE file inspector tool like PE-bear everything seems fine and in the disassembly view of .text section PE-bear is able to find name of functions referenced by "call" instructions.

Here is the screen shot:

[image: PE-bear disassembly view]

But sadly when I try to execute my binary it doesn't work and the debugger x64dbg (which also has a 32 bit version), can't find functions. So I suspect that the PE loader don't correct my IAT correctly for a reason I don't understand.
x64dbg also failed to display my "Hello World" string, but in this case it should be because I don't have filled the .reloc section for the moment.

Need I also fill the .reloc section for IAT?

Here is a capture of a debugging session, with crash at first "call" instruction.

[image: My crash in x32dbg]

And here is a capture with a similar exe generated by Visual Studio, in this case x32dbg is able to indicate functions names refereed by "call" instructions.

[image: A working exe in x32dbg]

PS: I am starting to learn ASM, so I may simply miss something like setting a CPU flag or anything else.
I give RVA of IAT to "call" instructions.

Comment: You don't have to create **.reloc** section at all, this is dedicated to base relocations only. Just make sure that the DWORD PTR in import section (`0x00404038`) is properly relocated and corresponds with IAT.

Comment: How can I check what the PE-loader relocate? I put the RVA of the IAT in "Data Directory" header block, need I do something else for the relocation of RVA stored in IAT (RVA to Hint/Name Table like ILT)?
Or you mean something else by "DWORD PTR in import section (0x00404038) is properly relocated", in which case I don't know how to make it relocated.

Comment: It seems that x64dbg relocates the image to a new address. If so, then you need a `.reloc` section to patch the references to import address table entries.

Comment: @jtxkopt This make more sense for me. I'll search how to fill the .reloc section.

Comment: The default image base is **`0x0400000`** for 32-bit images. Do you set this value in the `ImageBase` field of Optional Header?

Comment: @jtxkopt, yes is set the ImageBase to 0x00400000

Comment: @XavierBigand You can try to clear the flag `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE` for a temporary workaround. However all you need to do is to have a `.reloc` section and relocation table.

Comment: Removing IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE flag make my exe working, thx. The description "The DLL can be relocated at load time." isn't really clear for me, I just put it, because I reversed Visual Studio binaries.

Comment: @XavierBigand It means that `Windows Kernel` can enable `ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization)` for your program and locate your program data (e.g. Heap, Stack and any other Virtual Memory allocations) at random addresses. When it is set, this requires that your executable `PE` image must have a **relocation** table.

Answer (score 2):

Base relocations from **.reloc** section are used by Windows loader only when there is no vacant memory at the chosen *ImageBase* (`0x00400000`) address. This may happen when it is loading a DLL but not when it loads a simple `HelloWorld.exe`. Every time when the loader creates a new process for your executable, all 32 bit address space is free, no need to base-relocate anything.

You assembled `CALL GetStdHandle` as `CALL DWORD PTR [0x00404038]` where you expect the memory at `0x00404038` to contain DWORD PTR to the entry point of DLL function? That's not how the loader works, and how debuggers find the function.

You should have called an indirect near `JMP` instruction jumping to target DWORD from IAT instead.
In this case the loader doesn't have to pick up and relocate all your scattered calls of imported functions. Instead, it only walks thru ILT, makes the relocation once per each import and stores the final VA to IAT. You could see addresses form upper half of address space in IAT then, such as `0x7F******` or whatever the preferred load address of `kernel32.dll` is, as described in [Load-Time dynamic linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking).

ILT, IAT and Hint/Name are not the only essential components of your handcrafted **.idata** section, see also [ImportCreate](https://euroassembler.eu/easource/pfpe.htm#PfpeImportCreate) as an example.

Comment: 32 GiB?  I think you mean 32-bit or 4GiB.  Also, I thought Windows did ASLR by applying base relocations to executables.  If that's enabled, it would happen for a .exe.  Unless this exe specifically doesn't have that feature enabled; I only skimmed the question since I don't know many details about Windows executables' metadata.

Comment: @PeterCordes Whenever I load any executable from my Windows 21H2 by a debugger, ImageBase is always `0x00400000`, so I think ASLR is [disabled by default](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-security/turn-on-mandatory-aslr-in-windows-security/m-p/1186989).

Comment: I'd expect debuggers to disable ASLR for their child process; GDB does that on Linux.  If you `printf("%p\n", &main);`, do you get different addresses on different runs outside a debugger?

Comment: @PeterCordes I doubt that OllyDbg 1.10 from 2004 is aware of ASLR. 
And no, my simple StdOutputRIP program always says `0x00000000_004010000`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking; I don't have a convenient Windows machine to test on myself.  Interesting, I wouldn't have expected Windows to be so far behind in hardening against ROP / spectre attacks that they don't enable ASLR by default (in whatever tools you used to build that executable.)  Modern Linux distros generally configure GCC to build PIE executables by default, which get ASLRed by the kernel by default.

Comment: @Peter ASLR is enabled if a flag in the PE header is set, the same applies to DEP/NoExecute.

Comment: @Anders Wow! Which flag is it? I didn't find any occurence of `ASLR` in [PE format definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format).

Comment: @vitsoft The flag is **`IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE`**.

Comment: Thx @visoft for reply and links, I think that have more things to read now.
I am not sure about how using jmp is better than relocating all RVA I have, I may prefer to have slower loading time and faster code. If loading time are an issue, I'll use LoadLibrary instead. But as my goals are only learning, I don't really care for the moment of the "quality", my main target is to have a small compiler working.

Comment: If I understand correctly for an exe I simply have to remove IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE flag (VS don't use it), but I need it for a DLL in addition of .reloc section.
I am not sure to see the point of using JMP instead of CALL for both cases exe and dll.
I made a try with IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE and .reloc section that works, so I think now I can try to define my IR language and to generate binary directly  from my language.

Comment: @XavierBigand I think that optimizing your PE by nonstandard omission of thunk JMPs is the reason why debuggers don't understand the CALLs of imported functions. When I want OllyDbg to show the function name, such as `CALL GetStdHandle`, I have to navigate the debugger to the **object** file and let it load symbol names from there. Debugger is not capable to load them from PE even when the symbol table is included in **executable** PECOFF file.